# Is this the correct destination path below

Tags: php

I can not tell if this is working but I have a script which is in the "Exam_app" folder. Now in another script which is also in the "Exam_app" folder I have a variable which determines a file path:

```
$destination_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../uploads/";
```

Now I have an "uploads" folder within the "Exam_app". What I want to know is that does the file path above means that it will it will take the user to the "uploads" folder in the

Comment: that will look at a folder besides the Exam_app folder.

Comment: really? you can just echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']....

Comment: You should edit your question to finish your last thought. (There are also other typos/grammar issues.) However, immediately after this you could do something like 'echo $destination path;' to see where the script thinks you're about to upload stuff to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your folder "uploads" is inside "exam_app" remove the "../"!

i would either like this:

```
$destination_path = str_replace("//", "/", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/")."uploads";
```

or this (if your server has php5.3 or higher):

```
$destination_path = __DIR__ . '/uploads/';
```

otherwise:

```
$destinaton_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/uploads/';
```